# Google Cloud Function pulling from Pub/Sub subscription throws exception - Deadline Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Google Cloud Function in Python 3.7 reading from a Pub/Sub subscription in synchronous pull mode.

After running fine 1/hour for 24 hours, it threw this exception stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py",
>   line 57, in error_remapped_callable
>       return callable_(*args, **kwargs)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 824,
>   in **call**
>       return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line
>   726, in _end_unary_response_blocking
>       raise _InactiveRpcError(state) grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:   status =
>   StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED  details = "Deadline Exceeded"
>     debug_error_string =
>   "{"created":"@1580454091.145703535","description":"Error received from
>   peer
>   ipv4:74.125.202.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Deadline
>   Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>
> > 
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 346, in run_http_function
>       result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)   File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 217, in invoke_user_function
>       return call_user_function(request_or_event)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 210, in call_user_function
>       return self._user_function(request_or_event)   File "/user_code/main.py", line 39, in iteration
>       response = sub.pull(sub_path, MAX_MESSAGES)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/_gapic.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       fx = lambda self, *a, **kw: wrapped_fx(self.api, *a, **kw)  # noqa   File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/subscriber_client.py",
>   line 1005, in pull
>       request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py",
>   line 143, in **call**
>       return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
>   line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
>       on_error=on_error,   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
>   line 184, in retry_target
>       return target()   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py",
>   line 214, in func_with_timeout
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py",
>   line 59, in error_remapped_callable
>       six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
>   google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded

What is this about? Is it to be expected or a result of some configuration problem? If to be expected, how should it be handled?

The documentation ( view-source:https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/api/client.html ) on pull has nothing about this being a possible exception.

I ack the messages immediately after the pull completes. I only permit one function execution at a time. I have a 600 second acknowledgement deadline. A block of messages pulled at one time seem to be less than 100 in number. If this is about failing to ack a message, it seems like the error could be done much better.

Comment: It seems to mean that [there were no more messages to pull](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/9).  As a workaround I suggest to catch the exception and retry the operation

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange. The documentation says the pull may return zero messages, so I wouldn't expect an exception in that case.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an issue in the PubSub library. Apparently in the version `v0.45.0` the error does not occur. My guess is that the issue is related to the behavior of return_immediately. This flag is being deprecated, and the behavior is set to the equivalent of `return_immediately=False`, so the client just keeps the connection alive while waiting for new messages, until the underlying grpc deadline raises the exception

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I thought about using return immediately, because I just want to pull a batch of everything available at the current time, but I have actually left it unspecified, which should be the =False scenario. But maybe I should just be setting the timeout, as I was letting that default. It is hard, because the Python docs really leave a lot to guesswork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is raised by the client when there's no messages to read in the subscription. It is a [known issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/9) from the latest PubSub library versions >= 1.0.0. If necessary, you can downgrade to the version 0.45.0 where this issue was not present.

However, as a workaround you can catch the DeadlineExceeded exception and retry the operation again. Also, based on the [comment of Hemang](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/9#issuecomment-560374261), here's a small monkeypatch that you can add to your running code, which might help to get the same behavior as in version 0.45.0.

```py
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.gapic import subscriber_client_config as sub_config
sub_config.config['interfaces']['google.pubsub.v1.Subscriber']['retry_params']['messaging']['initial_rpc_timeout_millis'] = 25000
```

Finally, keep in mind that when using synchronous pull, [having many outstanding pull requests helps lower the delivery latency](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull), which in turn might result in higher latency pull requests (and DeadlineExceeded errors). Although, if latency is crucial for the application, you could consider using [StreamingPull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#streamingpull)

Comment: Thanks, @Tlaquetzal

Comment: I'm glad to help!