# Google Cloud Pus/Sub :: google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I was testing streaming processing of google cloud pub/sub.
Forward message from publisher to topic, reading the message on the pub/sub on apache-beam and checking it with beam.Map(print).

Reading messages from the pub/sub, it worked. But, an error occurred after reading the messages all.

ㅡ. This code delivers messages from publisher to topic

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time

# TODO(developer)
project_id = [your-project-id]
topic_id = [your-topic-id]

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# Configure the batch to publish as soon as there is ten messages,
# one kilobyte of data, or one second has passed.
batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(
max_messages=10,  # default 100
max_bytes=1024,  # default 1 MB
max_latency=1,  # default 10 ms'

)
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(batch_settings)    
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `[bigquery-schema.bigquery-dataset.bigquery-tablename]`
    LIMIT 20
"""
query_job = client.query(query)

# Resolve the publish future in a separate thread.
def callback(topic_message):
    message_id = topic_message.result()
    print(message_id)

print("The query data:")
for row in query_job:
    data = u"category={}, language={}, count={}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    print(data)
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    time.sleep(1)
    topic_message = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
    topic_message.add_done_callback(callback)

print("Published messages with batch settings.")
```

ㅡ. Apache-beam code [for reading and processing data from pub/sub]

```
# Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# [START pubsub_to_gcs]
import argparse
import datetime
import json
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    streaming=True,
    save_main_session=True,
    runner='DirectRunner',
    return_immediately=True,
    initial_rpc_timeout_millis=25000,
)

class GroupWindowsIntoBatches(beam.PTransform):
    """A composite transform that groups Pub/Sub messages based on publish
    time and outputs a list of dictionaries, where each contains one message
and its publish timestamp.
"""

def __init__(self, window_size):
    # Convert minutes into seconds.
    self.window_size = int(window_size * 60)

def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (
        pcoll
        # Assigns window info to each Pub/Sub message based on its
        # publish timestamp.
        | "Window into Fixed Intervals"
        >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size))
        | "Add timestamps to messages" >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestamps())
        # Use a dummy key to group the elements in the same window.
        # Note that all the elements in one window must fit into memory
        # for this. If the windowed elements do not fit into memory,
        # please consider using `beam.util.BatchElements`.
        # https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.BatchElements
        | "Add Dummy Key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (None, elem))
        | "Groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | "Abandon Dummy Key" >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)
    )


class AddTimestamps(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, publish_time=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
            """Processes each incoming windowed element by extracting the Pub/Sub
            message and its publish timestamp into a dictionary. `publish_time`
            defaults to the publish timestamp returned by the Pub/Sub server. It
            is bound to each element by Beam at runtime.
        """

        yield {
            "message_body": element.decode("utf-8"),
            "publish_time": datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(
                float(publish_time)
            ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),
        }

class WriteBatchesToGCS(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, output_path):
        self.output_path = output_path
    def process(self, batch, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        """Write one batch per file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. """

        ts_format = "%H:%M"
        window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        filename = "-".join([self.output_path, window_start, window_end])
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode="w") as f:
            for element in batch:
                f.write("{}\n".format(json.dumps(element)).encode("utf-8"))

class test_func(beam.DoFn) :
    def __init__(self, delimiter=','):
        self.delimiter = delimiter
    def process(self, topic_message):
        print(topic_message)

def run(input_topic, output_path, window_size=1.0, pipeline_args=None):
    # `save_main_session` is set to true because some DoFn's rely on
    # globally imported modules.
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read PubSub Messages"
            >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic)
            | "Pardo" >> beam.ParDo(test_func(','))
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":  # noqa
    input_topic = 'projects/[project-id]/topics/[pub/sub-name]'
    output_path = 'gs://[bucket-name]/[file-directory]'
    run(input_topic, output_path, 2)
# [END pubsub_to_gcs]
```

As a temporary measure, I set `return_immediately=True`. but, This is not a fundamental solution either.
Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Hello, I would like to clarify what "error occurred after reading the messages all". And can you provide the error message as well? Have you followed any documentation? Thank you!

Comment: @muscat Hi, An error occurs when the apache-beam reads all of the messages from the pub/sub. Here are the error-related documents. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue of the PubSub libraries reported in other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047371) and it looks that it was recently addressed with version [1.4.2](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/9#issuecomment-603093757) but not yet included in the [BEAM dependencies](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/beam/v2.20.0/sdks/python/setup.py) that's still using `google-cloud-pubsub>=0.39.0,<1.1.0`.

I made some research and found that `DataflowRunner` appears to handle this error better than `DirectRunner`, which is maintained by Apache Beam team. The issue has been already reported on [beam site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9988), and it's not resolved yet.

Also please be advised that the troubleshooting guide for `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#publish-deadline-exceeded). You can check if any of the presented advices could help in your case, such as upgrading to the latest version of the client library.