# ERROR i.g.i.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I create subscribers to pull synchronously messages from a pubSub Topic. I used the exact setting as from the documentation [example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull).

However, I am facing the following problem when I am trying to shut down subscribers and create new ones.

```
[pool-1-thread-8] ERROR i.g.i.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper - *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=47567, target=pubsub.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init> 
(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:93)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:53)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:44)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:612)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.
java:261) at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel
(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:340)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600
(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:73)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel
(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:214)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.
 createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:221)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider
.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:169)
at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:272)
at eu.hermes.esb.cloud.service.SubService.getSubscriber(SubService.java:48)
at eu.hermes.esb.cloud.runnables.SubTask.run(SubTask.java:31)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

my code for creating and shutting down subscribers:

```
   while (compositeConfigurationElement.getSubscriber().isEnabled()) {
        SubscriberStub subscriber;
        try {
            subscriber = subService.getSubscriber(compositeConfigurationElement);
            subService.pullAndSend(compositeConfigurationElement, subscriptionName, subscriber);
            subscriber.shutdown();
            subscriber.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (DeadlineExceededException e) {
            // this is a know issue at the moment ->
            // 1- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/4220
            // 2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012138/google-cloud-function-pulling-from-pub-sub-subscription-throws-exception-deadl
            // 3- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3648
            log.warn("Deadline exceeded for subscription");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception with the subscription service", e);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                log.error("Exception during wait", e2);
            }
        }
    }
```

so, **how to get rid of this error message** ? and
how on earth is this exception thrown although I am catching all exceptions.

Iam using **google-cloud-pubsub:1.110.3**

Comment: actully I think this is the recommened method to pull messages. which creating a subscriber and pulling and then shutting it down. I read it in the docs somewhere. 

and I don't think this is happening because Iam creating and shutting down subscribers because IAM SHUTTING DOWN SUBSCRIBERS. so, this should not give me this error message that says please shutdown the subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I was missing that when an empty subscription happens the pull request throws a `DeadlineExceededException`   which I am already catching, but I missed that in this case the subscriber is not shutdown.

so the solution is to shutdown the subscriber in the catch or in a finally block.